# UITableView how to add a custom UIImageView as a separator and set the custom position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView with a number of sections (not rows). I'd like to add the UIImageView as a separator between each sections at the center (except the last cell).
The space between cells is 30

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return headerView;
}
```

### The screenshot

I'd like to set the position like at the screenshot.
[image]

### The code I've made

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

The cell height is 81.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Some code
    UIImageView *separatorIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 96, 196, 2)];
    [separatorIView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayline.png"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorIView];
    return cell;
}
```

The grayline appears if I set the y coordinate < then cell height.
Thanks in advance.

### The result

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30; 
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (section > 0) {
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62, 14, 196, 2)];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayline.png"]];
        [headerView addSubview:img];
    }
    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom separator position is not possible because they are privately defined for its frame, apart from that if you need that kind of effect then you have to add a image in header like custom space and color with require view with that only you can get the desired view

Answer (score 1):

As you are setting a head view height you can add separator in header. Table View has a delegate method named "viewForHeaderInSection".

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 5)];
      [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayline.png"]];
      return img;
 }
```

If you set the separator image in this delegate method you don't need to do anything in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
Let me know if that helps... :)

**Edit:**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
```

`

Comment: I've tried 2 delegate methods (for header and for footer). The result is: http://s27.postimg.org/il5rynodf/2014_01_15_13_09_55.png

Comment: @ArtemZ.>> Don't set footer, and decrease the height of the heightForHeaderInSection 30 pixel is too big to be a separator. Make it 5.

Comment: >> http://s29.postimg.org/79n1g70on/2014_01_15_13_19_28.png How to set the space between 2 cells (sections) now? And how to set the width of the separator. `CGRectMake(0,0,196,2)` doesn't help

Comment: @ArtemZ. >> See my edit. Change you delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Separator color using setSeparator color in which you can pass image

like,

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayline.png"]]];
```

Comment: Man, I've read that. But how to set the position at the center between 2 cells.

Comment: You dont have to worry to put it in center separator is alwyz between two cells equally.

Answer (score 0):

just try to make the height of the last header as zero and see if it works.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if(make_cndition_for_lastsection)
    return 0;
  else
    return  30;
}
```